# Munkres Thm 19.5 and Axiom of Choice

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, set-theory, axiom-of-choice

> **Theorem 19.5 in Munkres** Let $\{X_\alpha\}$ be an indexed family of spaces; let $A_\alpha  \subset X_ \alpha$ for each $\alpha$. If $\prod X_{\alpha}$ is given either the product or the box topology, then $$\prod \bar{A}_{\alpha} = \overline{\prod A_{\alpha}}$$
> Proof. Let $x=(x_\alpha)$ be a point of $\prod \bar{A}_{\alpha}$; we show that $x \in \overline{\prod A_{\alpha}}$. Let $U=\prod U_{\alpha}$ be a basis element for either the box or product topology that contains $x$. Since $x_\alpha \in \bar{A}_{\alpha}$, we can choose a point $y_\alpha \in U_\alpha \cap A_\alpha$ for each $\alpha$. Then $y=(y_\alpha)$ belongs to both $U$ and $\prod A_{\alpha}$. Since $U$ is arbitrary, it follows that $x$ belongs to the closure of $\prod A_{\alpha}$.

I think that this part of the proof requires the Axiom of Choice because it says "choose a point $y_\alpha \in U_\alpha \cap A_\alpha$ for each $\alpha$". In addition, I know that "The Cartesian product of any nonempty family of nonempty sets is nonempty" is equivalent to the AC. So since we know $U_\alpha \cap A_\alpha$ is nonempty for each $\alpha$, we need AC to show that $U \cap \prod A_{\alpha} = \prod {U_{\alpha} \cap A_{\alpha}}$ is nonempty, proving that $x$ belongs to the closure of $\prod A_{\alpha}$.

Is there any way to prove this part of the theorem without using AC?

Comment: May I ask what's your endgame here? Are we going through Mukres and finding uses of AC?

Comment: I would like to, since the book sometimes doesn't say explicitly that AC is required to prove the given theorem.

Comment: Yes, because in topology the axiom of choice is so necessary, that it is almost foolish to write a graduate level textbook and insist on discussing it in every step of the way.

Comment: Then, most of the time is it okay to think that the proof of a theorem does require AC if it seems to, even though the Munkres book says nothing about it?

Comment: Yes. In a standard topology book, almost all proofs are going to require the axiom of choice in one way or another. Not all, mind you, some things can be salvaged even without the axiom of choice, perhaps with the same proof, or perhaps with a modification to the proof. As my topology professor once said at some point before talking about compactness (which was not too long into the semester), for those who reject the axiom of choice, the course is over.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No.  In fact, this theorem is equivalent to AC.  To prove AC from it, suppose $(A_\alpha)$ is a family of nonempty sets which has no choice function.  Let $*$ be a set that is not an element of any $A_\alpha$, and let $X_\alpha=A_\alpha\cup\{*\}$ with the indiscrete topology.  Then $\overline{A_\alpha}=X_\alpha$ for each $\alpha$, so $\prod \overline{A}_\alpha=\prod X_\alpha$ and in particular is nonempty since it contains an element which is $*$ on every coordinate.  On the other hand, $\prod A_\alpha$ is empty since $(A_\alpha)$ has no choice function, so $\overline{\prod A_\alpha}$ is also empty (in any topology).  In particular, $\overline{\prod A_\alpha}\neq \prod \overline{A}_\alpha$.